# Has the behaviour of Firefox's jssubscript-loader changed in version 26?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm using a jssubscript-loader to load in and attach some code to an object, like so:

```
const subScriptLoader = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/moz/jssubscript-loader;1"]
  .getService(Components.interfaces.mozIJSSubScriptLoader);
subScriptLoader.loadSubScript(url, myObj);
```

In Firefox up to 25, this worked fine. In Firefox 26, the subscript being loaded seems to no longer have access to the global scope. For example, it' can't find parseInt anymore.

Is this an intentional change in Firefox? Is there a workaround? Where who could I go and ask about this?

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the `parseInt` is not available? I tested a script with the line `var x = parseInt("17");` and myObj.x returns 17.

Comment: @paa - It's sort of confusing, as it appears to work in other code. But in this particular code, it will literally claim it can't find parseInt: "error: ReferenceError: parseInt is not defined". *sigh* Spooky action at a distance.